# Dynamically Resolving Static Content in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring web app that serves html files with nested black and white images. These images are in `<img>` tags on the front end, and served statically on the back-end using a ResourceHandlerRegistry and a ResourceHandler.

I've recently added a "Dark Mode". Switching to Dark Mode updates the CSS file that's in use. I've created a color-inverted version of each image. I'd like to serve images with inverted colors when the user is in "Dark Mode", and the non-inverted versions of the images when the user is not.

All of my images are currently in a folder /resources/img. Ideally, I'd like to resolve the resources in a way that the system will check for an image in /resources/img/dark, /resources/img/light, and if neither is found, falls back to checking in /resources/img.

I haven't found this kind of thing for static resources, is there any way to do this in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do this (though I don't doubt there's a way) through Spring. Instead, I added a CSS rule to images in dark mode: `filter: invert(1)`.